# Фильтрация DateTimeField по сегодняшнему дню

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Имеется поле в бд с типом `DateTimeField`, нужно выбрать только те объекты модели, у которых число, месяц и год совпадает с текущим числом, месяцем и годом.

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
Model.objects.filter(date__month=now.month, date__year=now.year, date__day=now.day)
```

Comment: Метод не работает. "2023-01-15 00:54:22.000 +0300" - start__day=now.day. Этот объект он не нашел, хотя дата сегодняшняя.

Comment: @Daniil Часовые пояса?. Ибо ```2023-01-15 00:54:22.000 +0300``` = ```2023-01-14 21:54:22.000 +000```